# limit x value during increment / decrement with jQuery previous & next button

Tags: jquery, increment, decrement

There are previous and next buttons below the main image, there is x amount of photos (7 in this case), I need to limit the value that's being added to x amount so that it can be only within the range 1 to x (1 to 7 in this case).

Obviously when user reaches x, clicking on next should go back to 1.

Problem can be seen here: http://mylandscapes.splintertaeal.com/gardens/regents-park.htm

Any help would be much appreciated.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var el = $('.nr');

  function change(amt) {
    el.text(parseInt(el.text(), 10) + amt);
  }

  $('#next').click(function () {
    change(1);
  });

  $('#prev').click(function () {
    change(-1);
  });
});
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the relevant code. As it stands, this question is a textbook non-constructive question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you should completely remove this code:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var el = $('.nr');
    function change( amt ) {
        el.text( parseInt( el.text(), 10 ) + amt );
    }
    $('#next').click( function() {
        change( 1 );
    });
    $('#prev').click( function() {
        change( -1 );
    });
});
```

And instead modify the following event handler.

```
var $nr = $(".nr");
$('#next, #prev').on('click', function() {
    var A = this.id == 'next',X=A?T:0,Y=A?0:T,Z=A?N+1:N-1;N=N==X?Y:Z;
    $("#display").html('<img src="'+$(E[N]).attr('href')+'" />');
    $(".display2").html('<img src="'+$(F[N]).attr('href')+'" />');
    /* Update the slide number */ 
    $nr.text(N + 1);
});
```

No need to have two event handlers in this case.

Comment: seems to be working but now images are not loaded unless button is clicked

Comment: @splinterteal, you removed the wrong code then. I edited my answer to explicitly show the code you need to remove

Answer (score 0):

```
        int i = 0
        $(nextbutton).click(function () {
          i++;
          if (i == 7) {
            i = 0;
          }
 showImage(i); // get i indexed image from array
        });

        $(prevbutton).click(function () {
          i--;
          showImage(i); // get i indexed image from array
          if (i == 0) {
            return;
          }
        });

I hope I understood your problem  in a right way .
```

Comment: In next.click showImage() function should  be after if statement, not inside